# How to disable the clickable property for Bootstrap glyphicons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I've included Bootstrap-3 glyphicons on my website:

```
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></a>
```

I have voluntarily omitted the `href` attribute because I don't need the clickable property (these icons are just used for decoration).

The icons remain clickable: the color changes when the mouse comes over them and a underline appears at the same time, giving the illusion that they can be clicked to achieve something...

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Simply don’t use an `a` element, but a different one, such as `i` …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `a`, instead use something like `span` or `i`. Style the `span` the way you like.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
```

**HTML icon in `a`:**

```
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Link with icon</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a span { your style }
```

Comment: Thank you @djl! I had obviously to avoid `<a></a>` tag which is made especially for links... This is definitely the simplest way to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
.glyphicon {
    color: #000 !important;
}
.glyphicon:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  /* Set your colour if you do not want to use "!important" */;
    cursor: default;
}
```

You can either set your colour using `!important` which increases the specificity to 100 or just give `:hover` the same colour. I would recommend the later to keep low specificity.

Comment: Your answer resets the mouse cursor. OP wants to remove the click. He is using the a tag. He just needs to switch to span. (or any other similar tag)

Answer (score -1):

```css
.avoid-clicks {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
   

<a class="avoid-clicks">try selecting text through me</a>
```

use pointer-events:none see this example